# Check if UR10 (Universal Robot) Finished job successfully

Tags: c#, events, communication, robot, universal

I am communicating with UR10 with C# under automation NuGet package.

How can I know if robot finished given job successfully?

we are giving UR10 jobs with scripts like this:

```
def FullCommand():
    global curent_j_pose = get_actual_joint_positions ()
    global current_b_value = curent_j_pose[0]
     movep(p[.556075771156, -.493695531905, .571111521277, 1.426415630227, .726027077406, .605252480495], a = 1.5, v = 0.6, r = 0.05) ....
end
```

For now we are getting this information from OnKeyMessageReceived event from PrimaryInterface

```
void OnKeyMessageReceived(int? DeviceID, KeyMessageEventArgs E)
{
    if (E.RobotMessageTitle.Contains("STOPPED"))    
    {
                
    }
}
```

Is this correct way to achieve this ?
Because I think sometimes this event is raised even when job was not finished successfully.

help.